# Using RSpec in Spacemacs with Spring

Tags: spring, emacs, rspec, spacemacs

When I try to run an RSpec test in Spacemacs, I get the following output:

```
RSpec Compilation started at Tue Feb 21 14:14:30

spring rspec --options <path to my test>
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  activesupport (>= 4.2)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Version: 2.0.0

Usage: spring COMMAND [ARGS]

Commands for spring itself:

binstub         Generate spring based binstubs. Use --all to generate a binstub for all known commands. Use --remove to revert.
help            Print available commands.
server          Explicitly start a Spring server in the foreground
status          Show current status.
stop            Stop all spring processes for this project.

Commands for your application:

rails           Run a rails command. The following sub commands will use spring: console, runner, generate, destroy, test.
rake            Runs the rake command

RSpec Compilation finished at Tue Feb 21 14:14:31
```

If I disable Spring (e.g., run `spring stop` in my console) this problem goes away and I'm able to run tests without a problem.

I'm wondering if I have something configured incorrectly. My Spacemacs Ruby configuration looks like this:

```
(ruby :variables
       ruby-enable-enh-ruby-mode t
       ruby-version-manager 'rvm
       ruby-test-runner 'rspec)
```

I also may not be understanding what the role of Spring is when running RSpec tests with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that spring is running, the latest spaces macs should auto detect the `spring.pid` and change it's command accordingly.

You can start spring explicitly by running `spring server`

or any `bin/rails` command.

**Spring also only appears to be supported when using the rspec test runner.**

If you have projects that switch test runners you can set them per project by creating the following file at the root level of your project.

```
# .dir-locals.el
((ruby-mode (ruby-test-runner . rspec)))
```

Comment: Added a note about having multiple test runners.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer incase other people end up here looking for help too.

I had to add the gem 'spring-commands-rspec' then it all worked fine.